# Can't add tween engine to my Libgdx project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx, tween

I did everything i saw tutorials do and i added all the dependencies to build.grable but then it askes me to add he inheritance to GdxDefinition.gwt.xml and GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt.xml and to refresh my dependencies by running the command $ ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies .

I have no idea where those files are and don't know where i am suposed to run that command, can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just found the answer. Adding the inheritance is only required for html projects. If you want to make a html project those files can be found here:

```
<my-project-dir>/html/src/your/package/name
```

You can skip this step if you didn't create the html project.